# keras , Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [64,280]

Tags: keras, nlp, embedding

I am doing a simple binary classifier , but something wrong happened, and why ?
note: I have override the related layers for supporting mask_zero
the details are following...
 my model is following:

```
def mymodel_v1(conf_dt):
    input_ = Input(shape=(conf_dt['sent_len'],), dtype='int32')
    embedding = Embedding(input_dim=conf_dt['vocab_size']+1, output_dim=conf_dt['embed_size'], input_length=conf_dt['sent_len'], mask_zero=True)(input_)
    flat = FlattenWithMasking()(embedding)
    dropout = Dropout(rate=conf_dt['dropout'])(flat)
    dense = Dense(300)(dropout)
    out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)

    model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=out)
    print model.summary()
    return model
```

and the train step is :

```
def train(train_fp, test_fp, conf_dt):
    train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y, _ = load_data(train_fp, test_fp)
    train_X = pad_sequences(train_X, maxlen=conf_dt['sent_len'], padding='post', truncating='post')
    test_X = pad_sequences(test_X, maxlen=conf_dt['sent_len'], padding='post', truncating='post')
    train_y = np.array(train_y, ndmin=2)
    test_y = np.array(test_y, ndmin=2)
    print 'data load and preprocess done'
    print 'train_X.shape: ', train_X.shape
    print 'train_y.shape: ', train_y.shape
    sys.stdout.flush()

    model = mymodel_v1(conf_dt)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')

    model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=64, nb_epoch=2, verbose=2)
    print model.summary()

    model.evaluate(test_X, test_y)
```

the config.dict is:

```
conf_dt = {'vocab_size': 200000, 'dropout': 0.3, 'sent_len': 280, 'embed_size': 50}
```

the output of shape and model.summary is:

```
train_X.shape:  (116389, 280)
train_y.shape:  (116389, 1)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 280)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 280, 50)           10000050  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_with_masking_1 (Flat (None, 14000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 14000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 300)               4200300   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 301       
=================================================================
Total params: 14,200,651
Trainable params: 14,200,651
Non-trainable params: 0
```

the traceback is following:

```
      File "train.py", line 31, in train
    model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=64, nb_epoch=2, verbose=2)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1598, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1183, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2273, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [64,280]
         [[Node: loss/dense_2_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](loss/dense_2_loss/Mean, loss/dense_2_loss/Cast)]]

Caused by op u'loss/dense_2_loss/mul', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    train(train_pt, test_pt, conf_dt)
  File "train.py", line 29, in train
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 850, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 455, in weighted
    score_array *= mask
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 865, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1088, in _mul_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops._mul(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1449, in _mul
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/homework/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [64,280]
         [[Node: loss/dense_2_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](loss/dense_2_loss/Mean, loss/dense_2_loss/Cast)]]
```

why is this happened? can somebody help me? ty.

Answer (score 0):

and I read some keras source code, the layers of `Dense` and `Dropout` are `support the masking` by default, and the `FlattenWithMasking` which I override is following:

```
class FlattenWithMasking(Flatten):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                self.supports_masking = True
                super(FlattenWithMasking, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def compute_mask(self, x, mask):
                return mask
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why your dense2 layer output only a shape 1? This sounds weird to me generally the output is at least 2 as the model rank outputs with a level of confidence.

The shape 64 which does not fit with the [280,64] you should at least have an something like [1,64] to do so you can use :

```
 tf.convert_to_tensor()
```

(you should multiply matrices and not matrix with a variable):